# Ruby on Rails: Session Object Returning Nil

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

For some reason when I try to access the session object it seems to be returning nil.

This happens mainly in ApplicationController but has also occurred in other controllers too.

"You have a nil object when you didn't expect it!
You might have expected an instance of ActiveRecord::Base.
The error occurred while evaluating nil.[]" - Error message received when accessing session object.

Does anyone know why this might be happening?

Comment: You should show some code. How does the method which raises the exception look?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

are you using rails 3 by any chance?  Rails 3 defaults to cookie-based sessions - sounds like you are expecting AR based sessions ...
to setup ar based sessions

```
#create the table
rake db:sessions:create

#rake the db
rake db:migrate

#tell you app about it in config/initializers/session_store.rb:
Rails.application.config.session_store :active_record_store
```